# Yup validation for Object with When condition is not working

Tags: reactjs

I am using `yup` in combination with `Formik` in my React application to validate.

Values of my radio button field `radioBtn` is `{ code: '123', display: 'abc' }, { code: '456', display: 'xyz' }`. Similarly I have two more options for this radio button. When I select the first option of the radio button the value will be an object as `{ code: '123', display: 'abc' }` and not as a single string.

I have one more drop down field `dropField` with options like `[{value: 'x', label: 'y'}]` which is `required` when `radioBtn` value is `value.code === '123'`

How can I write the `yup` validation for this functionality or what change should I do on the below code?

```
dropField: yup
        .object()
        .when('radioBtn', {
          is: '123',
          then: yup.object().required(),
        }),
```